# Регулярное выражение для нахождения всех страниц директори

Tags: javascript, css, регулярные-выражения

Нужно каждой странице вида: `http://сайт.com/zvuk/*` поставить фон.
т.е. фон должен быть на : `http://сайт.com/zvuk/1`, `http://сайт.com/zvuk/2`, `http://сайт.com/zvuk/3` и т.д.
Получилось регулярное выражение: `/^http:\/\/сайт\.com\/zvuk\/./g/`

Но что-то пошло не так.

Comment: `*` после `.` не пробовали ставить? `/^http://сайт.com/zvuk/.*/g/`

Comment: Вот тут можно потестить регулярку: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включая корневую директорию:

```
if (location.pathname.split('/')[1] == 'zvuk') {
    // do something
}
```

Только вложенные:

```
var dir = location.pathname.split('/');
if (dir[1] == 'zvuk' && typeof dir[2] != 'undefined') {
    // do something
}
```